# image retrieval from its values(euclidean distance) in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, euclidean-distance

I'm looking for a bit of assistance. I have calculated the euclidean distance and sorted too. Now I have to fetch the images having least euclidean distance! And I have no idea how it can be done.

```
import cv2
import CBIR as cb
import experiment as ex
from scipy.spatial import distance

result_list = list()
i = 0
a_list = list()
b_list = list()
a_list.append(ex.feature_matrix_ip)
while i < 50:
   b_list.append(cb.feature_matrix_db[i])
   dist = distance.euclidean(a_list,b_list[i])
   result_list.append(dist)
   i = i + 1 
result_list.sort()

while i <50:
    cv2.imshow('',result_list[i])
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

CBIR and experiments are two different modules, and CBIR will return bgr mean and glcm values, and experiment returns the same for the query image

Thanks!

Comment: can you please share what you have made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, using [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is pretty easy to sort and obtain the images with smaller distances:

```
import numpy as np

image_ids = ['A','B','C','D'] #Identifiers for each image. 
distances = np.array([0.01,0.2,0.3,0.001]) #Computed distances for each image in the image_ids array


ordered_indexes = np.argsort(distances)
for i,least_distance_id in enumerate(ordered_indexes):
    print "Position:"+ str(i)+ " ID:"+image_ids[least_distance_id] + " Distance:"+str(distances[least_distance_id]) #Print the ids and distances
```

Comment: Am I suppose to assign the index manually for each and every image in the DB? I'm confused!

Comment: If you want to retrieve the images, I guess you will need to "link" some image identifier to your computed distances. If not, how are you going to retrieve the image? :)

Comment: so i can generate the id's for the images in the DB using a for loop, so that it can do the work automatically? i'm new to this opencv and python, so full confusing! :(

Comment: hey, will this work for images also: 'sorted(range(len(mylist)),key = lambda x: mylist[x])'. ?

Comment: i mean, i have to display the least distance images, not the values.. i'm not able to display the images even after indexing them.